проблема с расположением subtitle

Сетку грида менять нельзя . Нельзя позиционировать отступом с помощью gap .Можно пользоваться только align-self и justify-self . Но при попытке отодвинуть subtitle c помощью  align-self subtitle прыгает , и не попадает в PP . Использовать margin-block-end  или start нельзя , это будет ошибкой ! что тут можно сделать ?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
